# How to get the Wikidata item's Q-number of a wikipedia page by BS4?

Tags: python, wikipedia, beautifulsoup

You can find namely **Wikidata item** under Tools in the left sidebar of this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariyalur_district). If you hover on that , you can find the link address as below with Q-number at the end.
https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityPage/Q15112.
How can i extract the Q-number?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

getUrl= 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ariyalur_district'
url = getUrl
content = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,'lxml')
#extracting page title
firstHeading = soup.find('h1',{'class' : 'firstHeading'})
print(firstHeading.text +'~')
```

Upto this, my code is good. I tried to get the Q-number by the below code but i can't. Kindly, guide me.

```
QNumber = soup.find('li','t-wikibase')
print(QNumber)
```

How can get the Q-number?

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to explicitly specify the selector you're looking for, that's `id` in this case:

```
In [1601]: QNumber = soup.find('li', {'id' : 't-wikibase'})

In [1604]: QNumber.a['href']
Out[1604]: 'https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Special:EntityPage/Q15112'
```

If you just want the number at the end of this link, you can do this:

```
In [1605]: QNumber.a['href'].rsplit('/')[-1]
Out[1605]: 'Q15112'
```

Comment: When i run the code [1604] in python3, the following notice appears in terminal  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a' what should i do?

Comment: @info-farmer Use "html.parser" instead of "lxml", that's what I used.

Comment: @COLDSPEED on the basis of your guideline, I chat with my friend and coded as below.

Comment: @info-farmer Good to know! Please upvote/accept if it helped. It helps the community.